# Error Handling not working as expected on Err.Num 3021

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

First let me apologize for the spaghetti code as I am not sure of the best way to handle errors like this.

The situation I run into is that our data gets moved between two different data centers throughout the year, so I need to test the connection based on the error number -2147467259, which happens on `cfRS.Open CIFstr, adoConn` in the top section of the code if there is no connection to that server.

I have tried using `IF` statements to look at the above error number, but those were not succesful, so below is the wonderful spaghetti code I have written.

Error Number 3021 happens on `cfRS.MoveFirst` within the `Branson:` section of this code when I delete the value from `Sheet1.Range("B103")` and I am not sure why the error is not being handled with the `On Error GoTo Err3021`.  The `ErrHandler:` in the top section of the code works just fine.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

CODE:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CIFIncoming()
    Dim adoConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cfRS As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Name As String, Address1 As String, Address2 As String
    Dim City As String, State As String, Zip As String
    Dim HomePhone As String, CellPhone As String
    Dim BSA As String
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim CIFstr As String, CIF As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

'\\\\BEGIN DATABASE INFORMATION GRAB////
'   1.  Sets the Connection String to the Data Base
'   2.  Opens the connection to the database
'   3.  Sets the SQL String to get the fields from the Data Base
'   4.  Defines the CIF Number to use in the SQL String
'   5.  Opens the Recordset
'   6.  Moves the cursor in the DataBase to first position



    strConn = [REDACTED]

    adoConn.Open strConn

    CIF = UCase(Sheet1.Range("B103").Text)

    CIFstr = "SELECT " & _
             "cfna1, cfna2, cfna3, cfcity, cfstat, LEFT(cfzip, 5), cfhpho, cfcel1, cfudsc6 " & _
             "FROM cncttp08.jhadat842.cfmast cfmast " & _
             "WHERE cfcif# = '" & CIF & "'"


    cfRS.Open CIFstr, adoConn

    cfRS.MoveFirst

'\\\\END DATABASE INFORMATION GRAB////

'\\\\BEGIN WORKSHEET INFORMATION PLACEMENT////
'   1.  Assigns each field from the Database to a variable
'   2.  Moves data from Database to specific cells

    Name = cfRS.Fields(0)        'cfna1
    Address1 = cfRS(1)           'cfna2
    Address2 = cfRS(2)           'cfna3
    City = Trim(cfRS.Fields(3))  'cfcity
    State = Trim(cfRS.Fields(4)) 'cfstat
    Zip = cfRS.Fields(5)         'cfzip
    HomePhone = cfRS.Fields(6)   'cfhpho
    CellPhone = cfRS.Fields(7)   'cfcel1
    BSA = cfRS.Fields(8)         'cfudsc6

    With Sheet1
        .Range("B104") = Name
        .Range("B105") = Address1
        .Range("B106") = Address2
        .Range("B107") = City & ", " & State & " " & Zip
    End With

'\\\\END WORKSHEET INFORMATION PLACEMENT////

'\\\\BEGIN FINAL DATABASE OPERATIONS////
'   1.  Closes connection to Database
'   2.  Sets the Recordset from the Database to Nothing
'   3.  Exits sub when there are no errors

    cfRS.Close
    Set cfRS = Nothing
    Exit Sub
'\\\\END FINAL DATABASE OPERATIONS

ErrHandler:
'THIS HANDLES ERROR 3021
    If Err.Number = 3021 Then
        With Sheet1
            .Range("B104") = vbNullString
            .Range("B105") = vbNullString
            .Range("B106") = vbNullString
            .Range("B107") = ""
        End With
    End If

    If Err.Number = -2147467259 Then GoTo Branson


Branson:
    On Error GoTo Err3021
    CIF = UCase(Sheet1.Range("B103").Text)

    CIFstr = "SELECT " & _
             "cfna1, cfna2, cfna3, cfcity, cfstat, LEFT(cfzip, 5), cfhpho, cfcel1, cfudsc6 " & _
             "FROM bhschlp8.jhadat842.cfmast cfmast " & _
             "WHERE cfcif# = '" & CIF & "'"

    cfRS.Open CIFstr, adoConn

    cfRS.MoveFirst  

'\\\\END DATABASE INFORMATION GRAB////

'\\\\BEGIN WORKSHEET INFORMATION PLACEMENT////
'   1.  Assigns each field from the Database to a variable
'   2.  Moves data from Database to specific cells

    Name = cfRS.Fields(0)        'cfna1
    Address1 = cfRS(1)           'cfna2
    Address2 = cfRS(2)           'cfna3
    City = Trim(cfRS.Fields(3))  'cfcity
    State = Trim(cfRS.Fields(4)) 'cfstat
    Zip = cfRS.Fields(5)         'cfzip
    HomePhone = cfRS.Fields(6)   'cfhpho
    CellPhone = cfRS.Fields(7)   'cfcel1
    BSA = cfRS.Fields(8)         'cfudsc6

    With Sheet1
        .Range("B104") = Name
        .Range("B105") = Address1
        .Range("B106") = Address2
        .Range("B107") = City & ", " & State & " " & Zip
    End With

'\\\\END WORKSHEET INFORMATION PLACEMENT////

'\\\\BEGIN FINAL DATABASE OPERATIONS////
'   1.  Closes connection to Database
'   2.  Sets the Recordset from the Database to Nothing
'   3.  Exits sub when there are no errors

    cfRS.Close
    Set cfRS = Nothing
    Exit Sub
'\\\\END FINAL DATABASE OPERATIONS

Err3021:
'THIS HANDLES ERROR 3021
    If Err.Number = 3021 Then
        With Sheet1
            .Range("B104") = vbNullString
            .Range("B105") = vbNullString
            .Range("B106") = vbNullString
            .Range("B107") = ""
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: instead of using Sheet1, maybe create your own worksheet variable and set the sheet explicitly?

Comment: That isnt the issue and unfortunately, my suggestion to define the Code Name of the sheet was denied.

Comment: OH, derp, i just read what error 3021 is, before you do `cfRS.MoveFirst`, do `If not(cfRS.bof and cfRS.eof) then` <insert rest of code>

Comment: To expand on why i suggest to do that, when your query's Where clause is `WHERE cfcif# = ''` then you have no rows, when you try to execute a `cfRS.MoveFirst` when you have no records, you get your error 3012. so you will want to ensure that you HAVE records before you try to navigate the recordset and then manipulate it.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you for that simple fix.  Please post it as an answer, so I can accept it.  Now off to Code Review so i can get help cleaning the code up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you do `cfRS.MoveFirst`, do `If not(cfRS.bof and cfRS.eof) then`.

When your query's Where clause is `WHERE cfcif# = ''` then you have no rows. When you try to execute a `cfRS.MoveFirst` when you have no records, you get your error 3012. so you will want to ensure that you HAVE records before you try to navigate the recordset and then manipulate it.